# const-correctness when passing complex types

Tags: c++

So, I have four classes:

*App* - this represents the entry-point for the application

*MainPage* - this represents the home screen

*Authenticator* - this represents a helper/utility class for authentication

*LoginPage* - this represents a login screen.

App, MainPage, and LoginPage all have pointers to an Authenticator, and it is, in-fact, passed from App, to MainPage, to LoginPage as the user starts the app, reaches the main screen, and is prompted to log in. App creates MainPage, and if MainPage needs to log in, it creates LoginPage. The Authenticator pointer is passed at creation.

Let's say Authenticator looks something like this:

```
class Authenticator {
public:
   std::string GetToken() const;
   void Login(std::string username, std::string pass);
}
```

Now, App will create a normal, non-const pointer to Authenticator but because I don't want MainPage to be able to modify Authenticator, I want it to store a const pointer to it (ie so it can only call const member functions on it). However, I would like LoginPage to be able to call non-const member functions, like Login(), so when I pass my Authenticator from MainPage to LoginPage, I'll need to cast away the const-ness.

**My question is**: is it bad to do so in this situation? Should a class that is not allowed to modify an object be able to pass it to one that can? Or would it be better to have App create MainPage and LoginPage at the same time, and give them both the same Authenticator to start with? My only problem with that option is that I create a LoginPage actively, rather than lazily, and I'd prefer to do it lazily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you may be proposing to design in undefined behavior, so yes, there is a better way.  Sure, you *can* cast away const, but if the object itself really is const then modifying it is UB.  If the thing needs to be modified then it isn't/shouldn't be const, period.  It sounds like a design flaw.  Where is this created?  Can `MainPage` store a const version and `LoginPage` store a non-const version of the same non-const object?  Can they retrieve it from another source?

Comment: @EdS. It's not UB in this case. The OP mentions the `Authenticator` is created as non-const.

Comment: @Angew: Sorry OP, reading comprehension failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an important part of the concept of logical constness. When a class accepts a pointer (or reference) to a const object, it's promising NEVER to use the pointer/reference in a way that could modify the object. This of course means passing along to someone else who could modify it.

In other words, if `MainPage` is planning to ask someone to modify the `Authenticator` for it (that is, pass a non-const pointer to it to someone else), it's also responsible for the modifications, and should thus be storing a non-const pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

From the Apps point of view, MainPage *is* modifying the Authenticator. If it's doing so directly or calling another party (LoginPage) to do it on it's behalf doesn't matter. So MainPage should get a non-const pointer and should then pass this to it's sub page for login.

If you want to make sure that your MainPage does not modify the Authenticator, you *could* implement a base class for it that stores this pointer and has a method to call the login dialog. The Authenticator is private, the method is protected. You can then derive your own MainPageDerived which has no (legal, non-hacky) chance to modify Authenticator but can call LoginPage if needed.

Note that I said *could* because for 3 classes I would think that's way overengineered. However, if you have more pages in the future, that may be a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I may well do that.

Answer (score 1):

From an interface point of view: if you have `MainPage(
Authenticator const* )`, you are promessing that nothing `MainPage`
does will modify the observable state of `Authenticator`.
Directly or indirectly—if `MainPage` later passes its
pointer to another class which will modify the object, you've
violated the contract.  Thus, in your case, it const-correctness
requires `MainPage( Authenticator* )`: the code constructing
`MainPage` doesn't care whether the modifications are direct or
indirect; it just wants to know what the contract is, and that
it is upheld.

Answer (score 0):

Give `MainPage` only what it needs. You can look at this a few ways. It could need:

- An `AuthenticationTokenSource` which provides an up-to-date `Token`.
- An `AuthenticatedExectuor` which performs `Action`s which `MainPage` defines, but `AuthenticatedExectuor` provides the authentication as it calls the `Action`

There are probably other ways, but those are the first that spring to mind.